# Посоветуйте маленький Linux в который можно установить браузер?

Tags: linux, webbrowser, virtualbox

Занимаюсь веб-разработкой. Хочу иметь виртуальную машину в VirtualBox маленького размера в которой будет только браузер Firefox/Chrome/etc. Всё остальное не нужно. Ubuntu занимает гигабайты и тянет много лишнего. Мне нужна крайне компактная и оперативная ВМ. На чем будет GUI не важно. Не нужны увесистые GNOME, KDE... Главное чтобы современный браузер работал.

Comment: Эти лишние гигабайты рублей 50 по текущим ценам на жесткие диски обойдутся, а потратите на поиски/настройку часы, если не дни.

Comment: последняя стабильная версия [linux — 4.8.7](https://www.kernel.org/). вот её и берите. правда, операционной системы там нет, но зато размер очень маленький.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, просили ж с интерфейсом графическим. Хотя, возможно, стоит куда-то в сторону докера копать? Но мне бы тоже системой хотелось целой.

Comment: Ставьте дебиян. И для гуя ихвсе (xfce).

Comment: @Qwertiy, у программы/библиотеки linux есть только api/abi, и никаких gui/tui в принципе нет. получаются взаимоисключающие параграфы. я ответил на вопрос про выбор версии этой программы.

Comment: ну типа разбариан

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, ну мне что, переформулировать вопрос за автора? Ну ладно, поехали. Для тестирования отображения сайта в браузерах в линуксе ищу дистрибутив с любым графическим интерфейсом, лишь бы можно было установить современные браузеры и увидеть, как отображается сайт. Хочу найти дистрибутив, который после установки будет занимать как можно меньше места и есть как можно меньше памяти. Подскажите такой.

Comment: @Qwertiy, в принципе, любой дистрибутив. ставите минимальную сборку — будет вам минимум установленного.

Comment: Если нужно тестировать, как выглядит сайт в браузере на линуксе, то и ставьте эту версию линукса.  Иначе Вы будете тестировать, как выглядит сайт на этой минимальной версии. gnome/kde/xfce тянут свой (или настроенный под себя) рендер шрифтов и набор шрифтов. Поэтому, даже на одной машине в разные DE можно видеть по разному отображаемый сайт.

Comment: @KoVadim, тестировать на каждой версии линукса - это несколько накладно ;)

Comment: Тестирование - оно вообще накладное. Я бы тестил для начала на ubuntu (именно ту, которую по дефолту предлагает). А потом смотрел бы в метрики, что бы узнать, какими браузерами и осями пользуются пользователи.

Comment: Согласен с @alexander barakin. Дело вкуса. Если не учитывать совсем уж маленькие сборки, навскидку - Manjaro Linux (простая и быстрая установка, ненужное можно выпиливать), Funtoo Linux (нудная установка, но ничего лишнего, нужное надо допиливать). Относительно работы под VMWare небольшое замечание - современные debian-based ядра криво работают, много оборудования выкинули, к примеру, не работает вмварьная сетевуха. А вот на том же Funtoo Linux - ядро gentoo-based конфигурируется и заводится на 100%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант легковесного Linux-а - это использование собственного docker-образа на базе Ubuntu с установленным браузером. 
Он не будет содержать ничего лишнего, кроме того, что вам необходимо.
[Для сборки docker-образа](https://docs.docker.com/engine/getstarted/step_four/) c установленным браузером firefox выполните следующее:

1. Создайте Dockerfile

   ```
   FROM ubuntu:16.04

   RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y firefox

   # Replace 1000 with your user / group id
   RUN export uid=1000 gid=1000 && \
   mkdir -p /home/developer && \
   echo "developer:x:${uid}:${gid}:Developer,,,:/home/developer:/bin/bash" >> /etc/passwd && \
   echo "developer:x:${uid}:" >> /etc/group && \
   echo "developer ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/developer && \
   chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/developer && \
   chown ${uid}:${gid} -R /home/developer

   USER developer
   ENV HOME /home/developer
   CMD /usr/bin/firefox
   ```
2. Из папки, где создали файл, выполните сборку образа

   ```
   docker build -t firefox .
   ```
3. Запустите контейнер

   ```
   docker run -ti --rm \
   -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY \
   -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix \
   firefox
   ```

После запуска контейнера у вас должен на экране запуститься firefox-браузер.

Также в общедоступном репозитории docker-образов имеется готовый образ с предустановленным firefox-браузером. Можно воспользоваться им. Перейдя по ссылке, вы найдете параметры для запуска данного контейнера.
https://hub.docker.com/r/chrisdaish/firefox/

Comment: А для тех, кто на винде?

Comment: @Qwerty, интересующийся не уточнил, какая у него хостовая машина используется. Может быть подобный трюк и можно под виндой провернуть.

Comment: А вот вопрос по поводу докера. Я так понимаю, что понимание образа в докере это типа как ревизия в системах контроля версий. Т.е. образ нельзя обновить изменив его, можно только накатить сверху новую версию. А если образ read-only, то куда он пишет свои данные в процессе работы? Например Firefox куда будет свой кэш писать и будет ли он сохранятся между запусками контейнера, т.е. образа?

Comment: Образ можно сопоставить с ревизией контроля версий. Только в создании новой ревизии часто надобности в этом нет, так как некоторые файлы вы можете перенести в файл игнорирования, которые вы не хотите отслеживать. Теперь детали...

Comment: @abg, он пишет туда, куда обычно пишется кеш в браузере firefox под обычным линуксом. И после остановки образа, без сохранения его слепка(ревизии), все данные будут потеряны после перезапуска контейнера.

Comment: @abg НО!!! вы можете примонтировать папку с кешем от браузера из докера в любую папку на хосте через [параметр -v](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/), тем самым у вас данные будут сохраняться на хостовой машине и не будет необходимости делать снимки docker-образов. Может смело просто перезапускать docker Все нужные данные у вас сохраняться на хосте. После перезапуска контейнера, контейнер эти данные автоматически подхватит из хостовой папки. То есть общая папка - это единое информационное поле между хостом и докером.

Answer (score 2):

[BrowserLinux](http://www.browserlinux.com/) - 93MB.

Запускать следует из ISO-файла (т.н. LiveCD). Следовательно, после создания гостевой системы в VMWare - из ее оборудования нужно удалить все ненужное, в том числе и HDD.

**По поводу свежести версии браузера**

Данная Live-версия линукса позволяет произвести обновление FireFox в два этапа. В окошке "About" проверяем обновление и обновляемся с версии 5.0 до 12.0, повторяем те же самые действия и обновляемся с версии 12.0 до 45.0.2. Дальше браузер не обновляется, и дает линк на объяснения "почему". На момент написания этого сообщение - последняя версия FireFox 49.0.2

Учитывая, что данный дистрибутив Live-версии - единственный способ использования такой обновленной версии под управлением VMWare, это приостановка гостевой системы, и последующее ее возобновление. Иначе, понятное дело, все обновления пропадут.

Comment: Староват. Свежие версии в нём удастся поставить?

Comment: Не в курсе - автор топика не указывал необходимость. Но и поставить просто не получится, ибо это Live-версия. Если только самому разбираться и попробовать пересобрать образ.

Comment: Из вопроса: _"Главное чтобы современный браузер работал."_ - тут есть слово "современный" ;) И вообще, тестировать сайт на старье - это себе дороже.

Comment: Да и вообще, думаю, с установкой лучше, чтобы можно было конкретную версию использовать.

Comment: @Qwertiy, "несовременным" может стать версия после очередного обновления. С указанием минимальной версии было бы понятнее. А несовременный - это Netscape Navigator )))

Comment: Ну лично я под современным понимаю, что я могу взять последнюю на данный момент версию и её установить.

Comment: Дополнил свой ответ - как обновить firefox на указанном дистрибутиве линуха

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48488/discussion-between-majestio-and-qwertiy).

Answer (score -1):

Поставь Arch linux.Он довольно легкий и сам по себе отличный.Цитата с википедии `«легковесный», простой и гибкий дистрибутив Linux, оптимизированный для архитектур i686 и x86-64, использующий последние стабильные версии программ и дополняемый поддерживаемым сообществом репозиторием AUR. Arch «будет тем, что вы из него сделаете», и рассчитан не на новичков, а на более опытных пользователей.`

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?